On the tribonacci constant, $K(k_{163})$, and gamma functions
I. Some results
Let $T$ be the tribonacci constant, the real root of $x^3-x^2-x-1=0$. Then the exact value of the complete elliptic integral of the first kind $K(k_d)$ for $d=11$ is,
$$K(k_{11}) = \frac{(2T)^{2/3}}{11^{1/4}(4\pi)^2} \Gamma\big(\tfrac1{11}\big) \Gamma\big(\tfrac3{11}\big) \Gamma\big(\tfrac4{11}\big) \Gamma\big(\tfrac5{11}\big) \Gamma\big(\tfrac9{11}\big)$$
There are similar $K(k_d)$ formulas for $d=11,19,43,67,163$ with class number $1$ below.

II. Definitions
Given class number $n = h(-d).$ For primes $d=4m+3$, we separate cases $d=8m+7$ and $d=8m+3$ for matters which will be clear shortly. In a previous post, we considered $K(k_d)$ for the first form, while this new post will be for the second form.
Let $\eta(\tau)$ be the Dedekind eta function where $\tau = \tfrac{1+\sqrt{-d}}2$ and gamma functions,
$$\prod_{m=1}^{d}\Gamma\left(\frac{m}{d}\right)^{\big(\frac{-d}{\; m}\big)}$$
with exponent $\big(\frac{-d}{\; m}\big)$ as the Kronecker symbol.

A. Form $d=8m+7$
$$w_d = e^{\pi\,i/24}\frac{\;\eta(\tau)}{\color{red}{\sqrt2}\,\eta(2\tau)}$$
$$\prod_{m=1}^{d}\Gamma\left(\frac{m}{d}\right)^{\big(\frac{-d}{\; m}\big)} = x_{d}^{-4}\times\left(K(k_{d})\sqrt{\frac{2d}{\pi}}\right)^{2n}$$
then $w_d$ and $x_d$ are algebraic numbers of degree $n$, with $n$ being the class number.

B. Form $d=8m+3$
$$u_d = e^{\pi\,i/24}\frac{\;\eta(\tau)}{\eta(2\tau)}$$
$$\prod_{m=1}^{d}\Gamma\left(\frac{m}{d}\right)^{\big(\frac{-d}{\; m}\big)} = x_{d}^{-4}\times\left(\color{red}2K(k_{d})\sqrt{\frac{2d}{\pi}}\right)^{2n}$$
then $u_d$ and $x_d$ are now algebraic numbers of degree $3n$ (which is one reason to distinguish between the forms). The obvious question is to determine the relationship between $u_d$ and $x_d$.

III. Class Number n = 1
There are six, namely $d=3,11,19,43,67,163$. For this class, then $u_d = x_d$,
$$\prod_{m=1}^{3}\Gamma\left(\frac{m}{3}\right)^{\big(\frac{-3}{\; m}\big)} = x_{3}^{-4}\times\left(2K(k_{3})\sqrt{\frac{2\cdot3}{\pi}}\right)^\color{red}2$$
$$\prod_{m=1}^{11}\Gamma\left(\frac{m}{11}\right)^{\big(\frac{-11}{\; m}\big)} = x_{11}^{-4}\times\left(2K(k_{11})\sqrt{\frac{2\cdot11}{\pi}}\right)^\color{red}2$$
and so on. So $(x_3, x_{11},\dots)$ are algebraic numbers of degree $3n=3$,
\begin{align}
d = 3:&\;x^3-2=0\\
d = 11:&\;x^3-2x^2+2x-2=0\\
d = 19:&\;x^3 - 2x - 2=0\\
d = 43:&\;x^3 - 2x^2 - 2=0\\
d = 67:&\;x^3 - 2x^2 - 2x - 2=0\\ 
d = 163:&\;x^3 - 6x^2 + 4x - 2=0
\end{align}
The first two are special,
$$x_3 = u_3 = 2^{1/3}\quad\\
x_{11} = u_{11} = (2T)^{1/3}$$
where $2^{1/3}$ is the Delian constant and $T$ is the tribonacci constant. For the next class, unfortunately $u_d \neq x_d$.

IV. Class Number n = 3
There are many, the smallest being $d=59$,
$$\prod_{m=1}^{59}\Gamma\left(\frac{m}{59}\right)^{\big(\frac{-59}{\; m}\big)} = x_{59}^{-4}\times\left(2K(k_{59})\sqrt{\frac{2\cdot59}{\pi}}\right)^\color{red}6$$
There doesn't seem to be a simple relationship between  $x_{59}$ and $u_{59}$, as well as for the rest. The number $x_{59}$ is the real root of a degree $3n=9$ equation,
$$-2^9 + 2560x - 3840x^2 - 5056x^3 - 1024x^4 + 512x^5 + 152x^6 - 
  32x^7 - 8x^8 + x^9 = 0$$
while $u_{59}$ is the real root also of a nonic,
$$-2^3 + 16u - 8u^2 + 4u^3 - 8u^4 + 4u^5 - 2u^6 + 4u^7 - 4u^8 + u^9 = 0$$
They are solvable in radicals.

V. Class Number n = 5
The smallest being $d=131$,
$$\prod_{m=1}^{131}\Gamma\left(\frac{m}{131}\right)^{\big(\frac{-131}{\; m}\big)} = x_{131}^{-4}\times\left(2K(k_{131})\sqrt{\frac{2\cdot131}{\pi}}\right)^\color{red}{10}$$
The number $x_{131}$ is the real root of a degree $3n=15$ equation,
$$
-2^{25} - 2030043136x - 821915811840x^2 + 504210915328x^3 + \dots + x^{15}=0$$
while $u_{131}$ is the real root of,
$$-2^5 - 64u - 128u^2 - 112u^3 - 160u^4 - 128u^5 - 128u^6  - \dots + u^{15}=0$$
They are also solvable in radicals. And so on for all odd class numbers.

VI. Question
We ask a slightly different version from the previous post. Given prime $d=8k+3$ with class number $n=h(-d)$ and the proposed equation,
$$\prod_{m=1}^{d}\Gamma\left(\frac{m}{d}\right)^{\big(\frac{-d}{\; m}\big)} = x_{d}^{-4}\times\left(\color{red}2K(k_{d})\sqrt{\frac{2d}{\pi}}\right)^{2n}$$
The equation of degree $3n$ for the algebraic numbers $x_d$ and $u_d$ can be found using computers. But why is the degree now $3n$, and do all $x_d$ have a closed-form in terms of special functions, just like the $x_d$ for class number $n=1$?

Your definitions fail to define $K$ and $k$. Also, you could save readers some effort by including a definition of the tribonacci constant instead of sending us all offsite.

@GerryMyerson I assumed the notation for "complete elliptic integral of the first kind" $K(k)$ is well-known, just like $\Gamma(n)$. Very well, I will make the necessary changes.

Respectfully, if a user can’t tell based on surrounding context in the question what $K$ and $k$ are meant to be, then perhaps this question is not for them to answer.

@KStar I agree. I guess sometimes we assume what we know, others also know. And if there's something in a post I'm unfamiliar with, I don't mind googling it. Different strokes, for different folks.

@KStar, respectfully, if a user can't tell what the symbols mean, then perhaps the question should be closed, and not reopened until the defect is remedied. Has it occurred to you that there may be other reasons why a user would want a poster to clarify meanings, other than expecting to be able to post an answer?
